# How does a proxy server handle non-http traffic?

Tags: vpn, proxy, squid

I have an application that makes an un-secure connection over a non-http port to a server daemon. We use this tool internally. There might be occasion for some of our users to work outside our facility. I don't want un-secure connections being made from the outside into our facility. This traffic is not encrypted and could pose a risk.

My thought was to use an application like OSX Proxifier to proxy my specific application's traffic to a proxy server over https using ssl. I would then setup a proxy server, but what I do not understand is how or if it is possible for a proxy to then forward that data to another server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few standard ways of proxying inbound general network traffic ("reverse proxying").

If the inbound traffic is only HTTP(S), then a web server can forward it.  See e.g. `ProxyPass` in Apache.

Arbitrary inbound TCP traffic can be proxied with [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS).  A SOCKS-aware client wraps its request in a SOCKS request, and sends it to a SOCKS server, which interprets and forwards the request.  This is often done with ssh, which offers the `DynamicForward` option to set up a SOCKS proxy.  It opens a port that listens on the client host, forwards SOCKS traffic over the encrypted connection, and interprets and routes it on the server.  Many network clients can be told to use a SOCKS proxy.

Another common way is to tunnel traffic over SSL.  stunnel for example will do this.  On the client it listens on a port, wraps the traffic within SSL, and sends it to an server.  On the server, stunnel unwraps the SSL and forwards the traffic to a configured service.

You can send different types of traffic to the same port, often 443, by using a port multiplexer on the other end to figure out what type of traffic it is and route it to the right service.  [sslh](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml) and [sshttp](https://github.com/stealth/sshttp) are two that handle the common case of multiplexing HTTP and SSH on one port - say wrapped in SSL and sent to port 443.  Finally [TCPMUX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Port_Service_Multiplexer) is a protocol that was developed for port multiplexing.  xinetd for example can interpret it, but it isn't implemented in any clients that I know of.  (You'd want to wrap it in SSL.)